# Observing NSPopupButton changes

Tags: iphone, cocoa

How can I get a method call when NSPopupButton changes? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just add an action method as with an `NSButton` or any other control.

Comment: Thanks, Graham. I don't know why I didn't think of that! It seems so obvious!